# MySQL Join not Producing Desired Results

Tags: mysql, modx

I'm working on writing a snippet for ModX that will find all document with the specified TV set to a user submitted value.

Here is a description of the tables I'm working with. 
http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/Template_Variable_Database_Tables

Here is my query:

```
SELECT contentid 
FROM prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues
JOIN prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues
ON prefix_site_tmplvars.id = prefix_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.tmplvarid
WHERE value="Red"
```

Currently it's producing results such as this:
http://pastebin.com/mEJ1w2be

Where each document ID will have a new row in the results for each Template Variable. So, for 7455 in the example there will be one array for the color="red" one for material="wood" one for size="small". Which, makes it difficult if I want to find a product that is red, small, and made of wood.

Is there a way that I could join these tables so that I could get one row per product with the document id and a set of template variable with associate values—not all broken up?

Comment: If you're only getting the contentid's, why are you doing that join? Just SELECT from site_templvar_contentvalues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
GROUP BY contentid
```

this will smush all the rows with the same contentid together.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. It was smushing them together but only showing one of the "values" each row—so I used group_concat(value) and it shows them all now. So, now I end up with some records with "red", some with "wood", and some with "red,wood". What would be the best way to filter out the records with only "red" or only "wood"?

Comment: `WHERE value="red" OR value="wood"`?